# Exclude javascript window resize from mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Is it possible to exclude/ignore that javascript from mobile devices?

```
function doSomething() {
location.reload();
};

var resizeTimer = null;
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
if (resizeTimer) clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
resizeTimer = setTimeout(doSomething, 100);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Class for Detecting Mobile devices
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};

var resizeTimer = null;

//if not mobile do resize
if( !isMobile.any() ){
  $(window).bind('resize', function() {
    if (resizeTimer) clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
      resizeTimer = setTimeout(doSomething, 100);
  });
};
function doSomething() {
  location.reload();
};
```

For your reference

http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/

Comment: Thanks! That look good. I tried it, but now the window will not reload on normal browsers after resize.

Comment: because doSomething() is missing.. I fixed it ! Try again

Comment: YOU ARE MY KING :) Works fine! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is just wrapping the standard resize DOM event, eg.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
}

$(function(){
    var mobile;
    if (window.width < 481) {
        mobile = 1; 
    }

    if (!mobile) {
    // All your stuff.
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/QW5WJ/3/)**

Comment: Can you show me an example with my code? I am a javascript beginner. Thanks so much!